# Console doesn't write the text correctly

Tags: c++

When I write "cmd.exe", is writes correctly.
When I write this code:

```
// TestText.cpp : Bu dosya 'main' işlevi içeriyor. Program yürütme orada başlayıp biter.
//

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wcout << L"Sisteme giriş hatası!";
}

// Programı çalıştır: Ctrl + F5 veya Hata Ayıkla > Hata Ayıklamadan Başlat menüsü
// Programda hata ayıkla: F5 veya Hata Ayıkla > Hata Ayıklamayı Başlat menüsü

// Kullanmaya Başlama İpuçları: 
//   1. Dosyaları eklemek/yönetmek için Çözüm Gezgini penceresini kullanın
//   2. Kaynak denetimine bağlanmak için Takım Gezgini penceresini kullanın
//   3. Derleme çıktısını ve diğer iletileri görmek için Çıktı penceresini kullanın
//   4. Hataları görüntülemek için Hata Listesi penceresini kullanın
//   5. Yeni kod dosyaları oluşturmak için Projeye Git > Yeni Öğe ekle veya varolan kod dosyalarını projeye eklemek için Proje > Var Olan Öğeyi Ekle adımlarını izleyin
//   6. Bu projeyi daha sonra yeniden açmak için Dosya > Aç > Proje'ye gidip .sln uzantılı dosyayı seçin
```

But shows this:
[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Try adding a newline (`\n`) at the end of the string you are trying to print.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with writing these:

```cpp
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
```